# TypeError: this.props.delItemRow is not a function for deleting item

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babel-loader

I have put in my whole day tried every method but to vain my efforts. I am  learning React how to make work a delete functionality but then to vain .
A simple TO-DO list where the delete is not working. I dont know where i'm doing wrong.

Here are the js files: display and addList, which is parent to display.  Using props the parent function is not being called.

display.js

```
      class DisplayList extends Component{   
  delRow(en){
    this.props.delItemRow(en);
  } 
render(){
return(

//  console.log("check"+this.props.list),
    <div>
    <h4>DisplayList</h4>
     <ul>
        {this.props.list.map((item)=>(<li key={item}>{item} <button  onClick={this.delRow.bind(this,item)}>D</button> </li>))}
     </ul>
    </div>
    );} }

  export default DisplayList;
```

addlist.js

```
 class AdList extends Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={value:'',disArrList:[]}
  this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.delItemRow=this.delItemRow.bind(this);
  this.updateItemRow=this.updateItemRow.bind(this);
}
    delItemRow(itemName)
{this.setState({disArrList:this.state.disArrList.filter(e1=>e1!==itemName)};
}
handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value:e.target.value});
}
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("submit"+this.state.value);
    let mycolletion=this.state.disArrList.concat(this.state.value);
    this.setState({disArrList:mycolletion});
}    
   render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="Todo">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
               <DisplayList  list={this.state.disArrList} removeItem={this.delItemRow} updateItem={this.updateItemRow}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        );}} 
    export default AdList;
```

Thank you any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prop you are passing is called `removeItem`, so you have to change it in your snippet.

**display.js**

```
delRow(en){
  this.props.removeItem(en);
}

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
       {this.props.list.map((item)=>(<li key={item}>{item} <button  onClick={this.delRow.bind(this,item)}>D</button> </li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm :) such a silly hting n i took the entire day n couldnt figure out thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In **addlist.js** you pass **this.delItemRow** in props as removeItem, 
so in **display.js** you can access to delItem with **this.props.removeItem**

if you want to access it, with **this.props.delItem** in **display.js** simply you can change it into:

```
<DisplayList  list={this.state.disArrList} delItemRow={this.delItemRow} updateItem={this.updateItemRow}/>
```

Comment: its not delItemRow={this.delItemRow}  it is removeitem={this.delItemRow}  its working have changed to removeitem thanks:)

Comment: in general, you have 2 ways to solve this problem, first, change the parameter name that you pass as props second correct the name props in a child, I hope this was useful for you

Comment: whats the other way please let us know